# Spring boot deploy on wildfly many logs when start application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wildfly, wildfly-8

When i just deploy my application on wildfly 8.2 everything is ok but there is many logs and application starts very slowly.

this is my spring boot pom configuration :

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And my logs for example but it is only small part of that logs :

```
23:24:23,734 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.734] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.jmx.server]
23:24:23,734 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.734] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.jmx.server] not found - trying original name [spring.jmx.server]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/spring.jmx.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."spring.jmx.server"
23:24:23,734 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.734] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.jmx.server]
23:24:23,734 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.734] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [spring.jmx.server] threw NamingException with message: spring.jmx.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java."spring.jmx.server". Returning null.
23:24:23,734 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.734] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.jmx.SERVER]
23:24:23,734 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.734] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.jmx.SERVER] not found - trying original name [spring.jmx.SERVER]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/spring.jmx.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."spring.jmx.SERVER"
23:24:23,734 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.734] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.jmx.SERVER]
23:24:23,735 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.735] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [spring.jmx.SERVER] threw NamingException with message: spring.jmx.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java."spring.jmx.SERVER". Returning null.
23:24:23,751 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.751] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring_jmx_server]
23:24:23,751 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.751] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring_jmx_server] not found - trying original name [spring_jmx_server]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/spring_jmx_server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env.spring_jmx_server
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [spring_jmx_server]
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [spring_jmx_server] threw NamingException with message: spring_jmx_server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.spring_jmx_server. Returning null.
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring_jmx_SERVER]
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring_jmx_SERVER] not found - trying original name [spring_jmx_SERVER]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/spring_jmx_SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env.spring_jmx_SERVER
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [spring_jmx_SERVER]
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [spring_jmx_SERVER] threw NamingException with message: spring_jmx_SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.spring_jmx_SERVER. Returning null.
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/springJmx.server]
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/springJmx.server] not found - trying original name [springJmx.server]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/springJmx.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."springJmx.server"
23:24:23,752 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.752] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [springJmx.server]
23:24:23,753 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.753] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [springJmx.server] threw NamingException with message: springJmx.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java."springJmx.server". Returning null.
23:24:23,754 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.754] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/springJmx.SERVER]
23:24:23,754 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.754] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/springJmx.SERVER] not found - trying original name [springJmx.SERVER]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/springJmx.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."springJmx.SERVER"
23:24:23,754 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.754] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [springJmx.SERVER]
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.754] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [springJmx.SERVER] threw NamingException with message: springJmx.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java."springJmx.SERVER". Returning null.
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.755] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/springjmx.server]
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.755] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/springjmx.server] not found - trying original name [springjmx.server]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/springjmx.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."springjmx.server"
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.755] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [springjmx.server]
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.755] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [springjmx.server] threw NamingException with message: springjmx.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java."springjmx.server". Returning null.
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.755] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/springjmx.SERVER]
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.755] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/springjmx.SERVER] not found - trying original name [springjmx.SERVER]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/springjmx.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."springjmx.SERVER"
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.755] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [springjmx.SERVER]
23:24:23,755 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.755] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [springjmx.SERVER] threw NamingException with message: springjmx.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java."springjmx.SERVER". Returning null.
23:24:23,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/SPRING.JMX.server]
23:24:23,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/SPRING.JMX.server] not found - trying original name [SPRING.JMX.server]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/SPRING.JMX.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."SPRING.JMX.server"
23:24:23,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [SPRING.JMX.server]
23:24:23,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [SPRING.JMX.server] threw NamingException with message: SPRING.JMX.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java."SPRING.JMX.server". Returning null.
23:24:23,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/SPRING.JMX.SERVER]
23:24:23,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/SPRING.JMX.SERVER] not found - trying original name [SPRING.JMX.SERVER]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/SPRING.JMX.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."SPRING.JMX.SERVER"
23:24:23,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [SPRING.JMX.SERVER]
23:24:23,756 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [SPRING.JMX.SERVER] threw NamingException with message: SPRING.JMX.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java."SPRING.JMX.SERVER". Returning null.
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.756] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/SPRING_JMX_server]
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.757] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/SPRING_JMX_server] not found - trying original name [SPRING_JMX_server]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/SPRING_JMX_server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env.SPRING_JMX_server
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.757] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [SPRING_JMX_server]
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.757] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [SPRING_JMX_server] threw NamingException with message: SPRING_JMX_server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.SPRING_JMX_server. Returning null.
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.757] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/SPRING_JMX_SERVER]
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.757] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/SPRING_JMX_SERVER] not found - trying original name [SPRING_JMX_SERVER]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/SPRING_JMX_SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env.SPRING_JMX_SERVER
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.757] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [SPRING_JMX_SERVER]
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.757] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [SPRING_JMX_SERVER] threw NamingException with message: SPRING_JMX_SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.SPRING_JMX_SERVER. Returning null.
23:24:23,757 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.757] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/SPRINGJMX.server]
23:24:23,785 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.784] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/SPRINGJMX.server] not found - trying original name [SPRINGJMX.server]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/SPRINGJMX.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."SPRINGJMX.server"
23:24:23,785 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.785] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [SPRINGJMX.server]
23:24:23,785 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.785] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [SPRINGJMX.server] threw NamingException with message: SPRINGJMX.server -- service jboss.naming.context.java."SPRINGJMX.server". Returning null.
23:24:23,785 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.785] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/SPRINGJMX.SERVER]
23:24:23,785 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.785] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiLocatorDelegate: Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/SPRINGJMX.SERVER] not found - trying original name [SPRINGJMX.SERVER]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/SPRINGJMX.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.seiton-homepage-ear.seiton-homepage-rest.env."SPRINGJMX.SERVER"
23:24:23,785 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.785] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiTemplate: Looking up JNDI object with name [SPRINGJMX.SERVER]
23:24:23,785 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.785] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JndiPropertySource: JNDI lookup for name [SPRINGJMX.SERVER] threw NamingException with message: SPRINGJMX.SERVER -- service jboss.naming.context.java."SPRINGJMX.SERVER". Returning null.
23:24:23,785 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.785] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mbeanServer'
23:24:23,786 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.785] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating instance of bean 'mbeanServer'
23:24:23,786 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.786] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration'
23:24:23,788 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.788] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- JmxUtils: Found MBeanServer: org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl@2222f2e4
23:24:23,789 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.789] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Eagerly caching bean 'mbeanServer' to allow for resolving potential circular references
23:24:23,789 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.789] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- CachedIntrospectionResults: Not strongly caching class [org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl] because it is not cache-safe
23:24:23,790 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12 23:24:23.790] boot - 27644 DEBUG [MSC service thread 1-16] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Finished creating instance of bean 'mbeanServer'
23:24:23,791 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-16) [2015-03-12
```

Comment: Looks like Spring Boot is configuring it's own logging. Kind of an OT question, but why use Spring Boot with a container like WildFly? I've seen a few questions around Spring Boot with WildFly and I'm trying to understand the use-case.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins From developer perspective there is some profit. I can create ear package that contains many wars, for frontend, rest and then one click to deploy all of them, next wildfly have got module class loader so many yours dependencies is set as provided and final ear size is very small. For me wildfly provide also cache container - infinispan.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the Embedded Tomcat Server From the Spring Boot App
First of all, open the pom.xml and add the Tomcat dependency. Next, you can change the scope to the provided. When we make the scope as provided that means this dependency will be available during compile time only and will not be available at run-time. This is because we need this dependency in compile time to compile the web-component-related files.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- Make sure that you changed the packaging to war -->
 <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Then, extend the SpringBootServletInitializer class in your Spring Boot main class and override the configure method. We need to do this to initialize the application in any other servlet container like JBoss.

You can see the code below that extends the SpringBootServletInitializer and overrides the configure method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringBootDemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
    return builder.sources(SpringBootDemoApplication.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

With this configuration, the application is ready to deploy to any external application server.

Once this is done, you can package your Spring Boot application as a war and deploy it to the JBoss server. To do that, you need to run  mvn clean package, which will generate the war file.